# Is there any idiom or expression that would mean "all my efforts wasted"?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for an idiom or expression that would mean "all one's efforts wasted".

I have found "[to have one's cake dough"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+have+one's+cake+dough). Can I use it for "all my efforts wasted" too? ( A non-native friend told me it is used for saying " all 'my plans' failed", not 'my efforts'.)

I want to use it in:

> John spared no efforts to provide his son with anything he needed for going to a medical college, but his son disappointed him by going to an art college. John accepted his son's choice but was really upset and felt ----(=all those efforts were wasted).

PS:

In Persian we say **"one's yarns changed back into cotton**".

(You know that cotton is changed into yarn by spinning, using a [spindle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spindle_(textiles)), that takes a long time and efforts, so "all my yarns changed back into cotton" means "all my efforts wasted".)

Comment: The yarn --> cotton one is great! I'm going to start using that in English because it's way better than any existing expressions!

Comment: It's worth noting that I've NEVER heard the "cake dough" expression. EDIT: Apparently it dates back to Shakespeare and beyond.  But I think it's safe to say it's not a commonly understood current expression, at least not in American English.

Comment: I see, @ChrisSunami, I just found it in dictionary, but I didn't know that if I can use it or not. :)

Comment: All that work, down the drain.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Your example works really well with *in vain*:

> John accepted his son's choice but was really upset and felt *all his efforts had been in vain*.

More than one dictionary uses similar examples to illustrate *in vain*. Take [Merriam-Webster (vain):](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vain)

> ―in vain
>
> **1** :  to no end :  without success or result < her efforts were *in vain*>

See [Oxford Learners](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/vain?q=vain) too, “All our efforts were in vain.” The connotation is though not quite that of the Persian idiom, that one’s work was undone, but that it was unsuccessful, and hence a waste of time and effort.

Comment: Perfect fit for the sample sentence.

Answer (score 66):

A good phrase for this is ***all for naught***.

Naught just means "nothing", so it's another way of saying all your efforts had no result.

"John accepted his son's choice but was really upset and felt his efforts were all for naught."

Comment: I feel like I've heard "all for nothing" much more often...

Comment: @Mehrdad you must live somewhere they speak a different kind of English than the answerer ;).

Comment: I'm no linguist, but I'm fairly sure *all for naught* is the original expression which occasionally gets bastardised into *all for nothing*

Comment: @Mehrdad yeah but either will work as a matter of taste and context. "Nothing" is plain and to the point while "naught" is a little more poetic.

Comment: What the heck are ngrams for: [*all for naught* vs. *all for nothing*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+for+naught%2Call+for+nothing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20for%20naught%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20for%20nothing%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Jacinto *All for nothing* is not a good candidate for ngrams. It commonly appears in contexts where it is not being used like *all for naught* because it's three exceedingly common words in a not-unusual order.

Comment: @Era I've checked the first pages of actual results. You get a few *all for nothing* in the sense of *all free of charge*, but the bulk of *all for nothing* is used in the sense of *all for naught*.

Comment: @Jacinto: And of course, some of those *all for naught*s may well also be in that *all free of charge* sense, particularly here in the UK.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sure. There's an *all for nothing* already a few answers down.

Comment: @Jacinto: Gah, missed that.

Comment: I personally like the word "naught" but it sounds very old fashioned.  In American English, at least, you wouldn't hear this expression in common speech (except from someone who deliberately favors older expressions).

Answer (score 42):

Try [go down the drain](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/go-down-the-drain).

John's efforts went down the drain.

Also, [turn to dust](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn-to-dust)

John accepted his son's choice but was really upset and felt his efforts were turned to dust.

Comment: "Down the drain" is really the most common idiom for this situation, at least in my experience.  "Turn to dust" is much rarer and sounds a bit overwrought.

Comment: "down the pan" is a variant on this.

Comment: Other variants include "down the toilet" and "down the tubes"

Comment: Or even 'down the shitter' if you want to get really coarse.

Comment: I particularly used "poured down the drain" to invoke the kitchen sink.

Answer (score 21):

They **went up in smoke.**

> go up in smoke
>   If a plan or some work goes up in smoke, it is spoiled
>   or wasted.
>   Then his business went bankrupt and 20 years of hard work
>   went up in smoke.

go up in smoke. (n.d.) Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms. (2006). Retrieved May 5 2016 from http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+up+in+smoke

Answer (score 15):

Although not a particularly poetic idiom, you can just say **it was all for nothing**.

Or, if you want to put emphasis on needing to recover from a failed effort, you can say **back to the drawing board** or **back to square one**.

> Start again on a new design or plan after the failure of an earlier attempt.

[Source.](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/back-to-the-drawing-board.html)

Answer (score 13):

I would have used **[to no avail](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+no+avail)**.

> **to no avail** - without any benefit or result
>
> The boy pushed against the door *to no avail* - something heavy was holding it shut.

For your specific sentence I would rearrange it to something like:

> John spared no efforts to provide his son with anything he needed for going to a medical college but **to no avail**, his son disappointed him by going to an art college. ...

Comment: Thanks, @Old Curmudgeon. How should I use it in my example? :)

Comment: @Soudabeh - Added a possible use.

Answer (score 11):

If you specifically want an echo of the Persian expression, you might say your plans have **unraveled** or **come undone**, both of which convey the sense of something completed working its way backwards to an incomplete state.

Answer (score 11):

I like the phrase "**an exercise in futility"** to describe a lost cause.

*John accepted his son's choice but was really upset and felt his efforts were an exercise in futility.*

Answer (score 8):

Simon Bolivar's last words were supposedly "I have plowed the sea."

Comment: Probably more comment-worthy than answer-worthy, but I liked the quote so I upvoted

Comment: I like this one. But a source or quote and a rephrasing of the OP's sample sentence using your "have plowed the sea" would make your answer more useful and anttractive.

Comment: Poetic, but very obscure.

Answer (score 7):

What about [**down the toilet**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/down+the+toilet)

e.g. My business is going down the toilet after all these years...

Comment: I'd say that means more like "failed completely"; it's a reflection about the result not about the effort itself.

Answer (score 5):

Two options:

John spared no efforts to provide his son with anything he needed for going to a medical college, but his son disappointed him by going to an art college. John accepted his son's choice but was really upset that his sacrifices were just a ***fool's errand***.

Or

John spared no efforts to provide his son with anything he needed for going to a medical college, but his son disappointed him by going to an art college. John accepted his son's choice but was really upset and felt ***as though he had been chasing the white whale***. (a reference to Herman Melville's *Moby Dick*)

Answer (score 5):

I think ***["fruitless"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fruitless)*** works well here.

> John's efforts to get his son to law school proved fruitless.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit crude and graphic, but my favourite British idiom for something completely futile is "pissing into the wind":

- ["You can try to change her mind if you like, but you'll be pissing in the wind."](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-pissing-in-the-wind)
- ["The government is spitting in the wind if they think a few regulations will stop multinational companies from avoiding tax." / "Trying to get a pay increase here is like pissing in the wind."](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+pissing+into+the+wind)

Apparently it's [an Italian proverb and may be in American English also](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/piss-in-the-wind).

Defined to me as "to waste time trying to achieve something futile".

Answer (score 3):

You could try: **Out the window**, or maybe **Pointless**!

Answer (score 2):

you could use a phrase that also implies the dad had a plan.
"...felt his plans were of mice & men"

It references a longer quote "the best laid plans of mice & men often go awry"
You can see the dictionary give some info:
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/the-best-laid-plans-of-mice-and-men-often-go-awry

Answer (score 2):

I like the one I believe coined by Douglas Adams: "You are rearranging deck-chairs on the Titanic."

Depending on the audience, you can substitute other doomed liners: the Lusitania, the Andrea Doria, even the Costa Concordia.

Answer (score 2):

The common ones you already got are: all your work is "down the drain"/ "down the toilet"/ "all in vain"

**"back to square one"** covers it if you're required to make another try.

**"spinning your wheels"** describes both your situation and the process.

If you're in a big predicament or you've run out of options/time then you're colloquially:
**"up s### creek [without a paddle]"/ "up the creek"/ "s### out of luck" / "SOL"**

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t been able to come up with a metaphorical idiom which is exactly equivalent to the spinning one, but some of the phrases that might be used in British English are: 
‘but was really upset that *his plans had come to naught*.’ 
‘but was really upset that *he had built his house upon the sand*’ which is an allusion to Matthew 7:42-72 
‘but was really upset that *his house of cards had come tumbling down*’:  similar to house built on sand, lots of effort going into something which has a poor foundation, which then fails. Both of these have the effect of suggesting the son is seen as the weak foundation, which may not be what you require. 
but was really upset ‘*that it had all come crashing down around his ears*’, again this is similar to the previous two, an is analogous to a poorly built structure. This one implies that the loss is felt to be catastrophic. 
‘but was really upset to realise *he had counted his chickens before they hatched*’ would mean that he had built up his expectations on something that wasn’t within his control. 
but was really upset and felt *it had all come apart at the seams*’ where ‘it’ signifies the plan for his son’s future and is analogous to a poorly made garment. 
NB It is possible you have an incorrect word in your spinning example, if  by ‘yard’ you mean ‘spun thread’, I think you want ‘yarn’, but if you mean ‘lengths [of yarn], ‘yards’ might be acceptable.

Comment: Thank for reply,  @Spagirl. I meant "thread", i.e. when the cotton is spun it is changed into yarn/ thread. Shall I use "all my yarns"? :)

Comment: @Soudabeh Unless anyone else can comment otherwise, I think 'yard' in this usage is incorrect. 'Yar*n*' means 'spun thread'.

Comment: @Soudabeh what you have now looks fine to me.

Comment: These expressions are all common in American English as well.

Answer (score 1):

It’s probably used more to describe things, nerves, and dreams (but perhaps the Father in your scenario had had some dreams about his Son being a doctor!), but **“Shot {all} to Hell/pieces”** can also work to describe “ruined, wasted” *time* and *effort*, as in the top definition for [“Shot to Hell”](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shot%20to%20hell) from ‘Urban Dictionary’:

> My computer just froze and I hadn't back[ed] up my data, three hours
>   of writing a thousand-word term paper just **shot to hell**.

In your example sentence it would give:

“John accepted his son's choice but was really upset and  couldn’t help but feeling that his efforts (and dreams for his Son) had just been **shot all to Hell/pieces**.”

Especially if Father and Son have been arguing about this issue all along, “beat[ing] a dead horse”  is an expression that already contains the notion of “wasted effort” in it (and would therefore not require you to use “his efforts” in the sentence, as “Shot all to Hell” does).

Regardless of whether the Son’s artistic preferences have always known to Dad or the announcement was a total surprise, you could consider using it, although it would require you describe how the Father **now** feels about his **past** effort (perhaps by changing “felt” to “wondered”) because otherwise it will seem as if the Father is still trying to convince the Son:

“John accepted his son's choice but was really upset and wondered if he’s just been [**beating a dead horse**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/beat-a-dead-horse) for all these years.

> **beat a dead horse**  US informal (UK informal flog a dead horse)
>    to waste effort on something when there is no chance of succeeding ...

(from *Cambridge Dictionaries Online*)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has an accepted answer, but I had a need for a similar phrase (in a slightly different context). I settled on paraphrasing Shakespeare, the original being "All sound and fury, signifying nothing." [Wikipedia - Macbeth, Act 5 Scene 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomorrow_and_tomorrow_and_tomorrow).

In the father/son context, "John accepted his son's choice, but saw that his words had been **only sound and fury**, resulting in nothing." Not perfect for this context, but a nicely poetic idiom nonetheless.

Answer (score -2):

*His efforts went **down a rathole***

> DOWN THE RATHOLE *idiom* (*chiefly AmEng*)
>
> For a worthless purpose or purposes: *Seeing your inheritance disappear down the rathole.*
>
> [Random House Webster’s Unabridged Dictionary](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=24960)
>
> *The metaphor comes from old farmhouses and settlers' cabins with wooden floors. Inevitably, holes would appear as knots dropped out of the surrounding wood. The holes were called "rat holes" because rodents used them for coming and going.*
>
> [sfgram on WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/go-down-the-rathole.1238574/)