# Word for hardwork gone into drain

Tags: word-choice, idioms

Whats a polite way to say "all the hardwork and late night work I did last night goes in drain" ,a funny way to say it would be also good

Comment: The expression is: hard work that has gone down the drain. You might want to correct your question....

Comment: possible duplicate - [is-there-any-idiom-or-expression-that-would-mean-all-my-efforts-wasted](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323630/is-there-any-idiom-or-expression-that-would-mean-all-my-efforts-wasted)

Comment: possible duplicate - [https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323630/is-there-any-idiom-or-expression-that-would-mean-all-my-efforts-wasted]

Comment: There's nothing offensive about "all my hard work has gone down the drain", it's not like "all my hard work has gone down the toilet" or even ”all my hard work has gone down the pan”, but the most formal and least picturesque way to say it would be "all my hard work has been wasted".

Comment: Sorry to say that's not a Question about English, nor even language in general. That's clearly a question about style and personal choice, which don't belong here…

Answer (score -1):

> All the hardwork and late night work I did last night and then,
>   **phut**!

**phut** [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/phut)

> Used to convey the suddenness of a malfunction, disappearance, ending,
>   etc.

As in:

> You just spent the last five hours carefully crafting a document and
>   then, phut!